# images are not rendering on react.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, image

I create a react app and make a test component and I try to render it and it didn't render

this is the component:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsNH1.png

and this is the main App.js file:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8lY7.png

and this is my result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQrFd.png

why is my test component not rendering?

Comment: Don't post your code as images, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React components must begin with a capital letter. Non-capitalized names are considered by JSX to be just regular HTML tags (like `div`), so your output markup will be just `<test />`.

Quoth [the JSX documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#specifying-the-react-element-type):

> The first part of a JSX tag determines the type of the React element.
>
> Capitalized types indicate that the JSX tag is referring to a React component. These tags get compiled into a direct reference to the named variable, so if you use the JSX  expression, Foo must be in scope.

Your `test` component must be named `Test`.

Comment: yeah it solve my error but now it give me another error on web